# Why Apache stop working after installing PHP MongoDB driver in PHP7.0.22

Tags: php, mongodb, macos

Why Apache stop working after installing PHP MongoDB driver in PHP7.0.22 on Mac sierra on MAMP 4.2.1? I followed below step brew tap homebrew/PHP brew install php70-MongoDB extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-MongoDB/MongoDB.so"

Apache logs

[Mon Jan 08 19:32:00 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 9604)
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.0.22 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 08 19:34:38 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: Have you had a look at Apache’s log? Normally it is more useful than someone just guessing without any information

Comment: Obviously because banana jammas in havana. Check your logs and update your question with something relevant.

Comment: Apache log info 
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:00 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 9604)
[Mon Jan 08 19:32:52 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.0.22 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 08 19:34:38 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: Also when i am running command(php -i | grep 'php.ini') on Terminal its showing 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini

But in MAMP phpinfo page its showing 
Loaded Configuration File  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/conf/php.ini